# Is there a way in Python to not use the with statement and also don't need to manually invoke .close?

Tags: python

In `Python` when you open a file you should do this:

```py
# automatically calls .close method on exit from the with statement
with open("my_file.txt", "r") as f:
    ...
```

Or this:

```py
try:
    f = open("my_file.txt", "r")
    ...
except:
    ...
finally:
    f.close()
```

However, I would like something like this.

```py
f = open("my_file.txt", "r")
# operate with the file
...
# file is not going to be referenced anymore
# or there has been an exception
# close the file but without manually calling the f.close method
```

I know that the garbage collector will probably close the file but I want to explicitly do it **without manually doing it** or doing a `with` statement.

Is there a way to do this using any `magic` class methods or using the `contextlib` library or just any other library?

### Use case

The reason I want something like this is because I am using a `httpx.AsyncClient` in a `python` module in different `functions` of the `script`. I would like to instead of passing to each function the `httpx.AsyncClient` instance as parameter just define it once at the start of the script and if something fails (exceptions, etc...) automatically close it.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to call `close() ` may be if we know the intent we might be able to help better

Comment: @Ángel this is not possible and a good thing, **explicit is better than implicit**

Comment: I am using a `httpx.AsyncClient` in a `python` module in different functions of the code. I would like to instead of passing to each function the `httpx.AsyncClient` instance as parameter just define it once at the start of the script and if something fails (`exceptions`,  etc...) automatically close it @shoaib30

Comment: @Ángel The best way to do that would be by wrapping your code in `try` `except` and `finally` and call `close()` in finally. I can drop it in an anwer if you'd like

Comment: I know I could do this @shoaib30, but I don't want to nest all my code. BTW I am going to add `try except finally` in the answer

Comment: @mozway **Flat is better than nested.**

Comment: then use `.close()` is it flat

Comment: @mozway Also, doing this `magic method` that will automatically close the file will be explicit because I will be using it

Comment: @Ángel I am not very familiar with https.AsyncClient, is it serving requests? if so, you don't need to nest it, just use a form of dependency injection for the requests and on competition of request close it

Comment: @shoaib30 I guess there isn't any way to do what I am trying. If you want post an answer with the `try except finally` statements and if nobody answers a better question in a couple days I will mark it as the answer

Comment: "I want to explicitly do it without manually doing it" What do you consider explicit then? ``with`` is usually the means for explicit lifetime management, but of course you have to *manually* write it in your code. ``contextlib`` will also need a ``with``. It seems that the question excludes any viable answer.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi isn't  `f = auto_close_on_exit(open("my_file.txt"))` explicit enough?

Comment: @Ángel ``auto_close_on_exit`` seems to be functionally equivalent to ``with``. Which you explicitly don't want.

Comment: Are you sure that an object's close() function (if it has one) is called upon garbage collection? I doubt that very much

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I just posted a "use case"  to explain why I want something that is flat that I don't need to nest all my code using the `with` statement

Comment: A ``httpx.AsyncClient`` will need ``async`` facilities. This is something much more complex than what the question shows right now.

Comment: @Ángel would calling [GC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) explicitly and hooking onto the callbacks and ensuring close help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING**

**I'll leave the answer as is because it answers to the original question. But anyone looking at this should be warned that it does not work with async. You can see more details about this in the comments below**

With [atexit module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) maybe ?

```
import atexit

f = open("my_file.txt", "r")

@atexit.register
def closefile():
    f.close()

# operate with the file
# ...
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for more or less. There is only one thing missing. Is there a way to close this file when it's not being referenced anymore? not only at the end of the script as a clean up function

Comment: @Ángel Not to my knowledge.

Comment: This won't work for the OP's "hidden" use-case of ``httpx.AsyncClient``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am genuinely curious why it would not work ?

Comment: why not @MisterMiyagi?, this will automatically close the connection/file at the end of the script even if there's an exception right?

Comment: @Ángel not if the script ends unexpectedly. In that case nothing works I guess

Comment: @NikoB Because an async object needs ``async`` facilities for proper cleanup. ``atexit`` is only meant for synchronous cleanup.

Comment: I can take that risk  "Note: The functions registered via this module are not called when the program is killed by a signal not handled by Python, when a Python fatal internal error is detected, or when os._exit() is called." https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html @shoaib30

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I could call `asyncio.run(client.aclose())` inside the `atextit` right?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I just did a script using `asyncio.run` and everything worked fine

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'll take your words on this as I am not familiar at all with `async`.

Comment: While it seem to work at first, when multiple `asyncio.run` are executed it will raise  `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`

Comment: I added a warning about using this answer with `async`

Answer (score 0):

As per the question, you want to ensure a file or AsyncClient is closed on completion or on exception.

There are two requirements for it:

- Know when the script completes - end of file/ return of function
- Know when an error occurred - catch exceptions

The simplest way to know both is to use `finally`. This would execute when the function/script completes as well as when an error occurs.

```py
try:
    f = open("my_file.txt", "r")
    ...
except:
    ...
finally:
    if f not None:
        f.close()
```

*Note: Ensure you check if f is not `None` as an exception could have been raised while opening too!*

Comment: This is just a convoluted way of writing ``with``.

Comment: The OP does not want to pass the pointer to each function, and not nest all function calls inside `with`. This would allow some level of flexibility to check the completion of a function and close it when done.

Comment: I mean this is *literally* what ``with`` desugars to for files.